# Is it possible run grunt command after saving code in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, gruntjs

I'm new to FrontEnd and coding JS in typescript. Every time after a code change I would like to: *save code -> compile (grunt) it on command -> reload web page*. It's a job. Is it possible to run 'grunt' automatically after saving code in VSCode like *save code-> compile ts to js -> reload page*.
(I would like to use grunt for changing all the ts files of the project to js).

I've tried to use tsconfig.json and tasks.json to solve it, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to run 'grunt' automatically after save code in VSCode like save code-> compile ts to js -> reload page. (I should grunt for change all project's ts file to js ).

Yes. You can detect file save in VSCode easily using the `onDidSaveTextDocument` extension point and run whatever code you want.

- Reference https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api